# CWE based Test Suite for Python

Tags: python, testing, automated-tests

Is there a widely known test suite with testcases based on CWEs like the **Juliet Test Suite for C/C++** from **NIST** for Python? I was not able to find a ready to use solution, only plugins like unittest where you can build your own collection.

The purpose would be to evaluate the performance of different static code analysis tools.

Comment: Not sure if useful for you, but [GitHub CodeQL tool](https://github.com/github/codeql) appears to have queries for many CWEs in Python code https://codeql.github.com/codeql-query-help/python-cwe/ and I think the query sources are available https://github.com/github/codeql/tree/codeql-cli/latest/python/ql/src. That is the inverse of what you wanted (test-cases, i.e. examples of each CWE vuln) but could maybe be a starting point if nothing else is available.

Comment: Thank you for the information, as you already mentioned the best case would be if there is something available already that is ready for testing, so this is not quite what I'm looking for. But that would be a good starting point if I need to create something myself.